# Does Wordpress disable RewriteRule in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

No matter what I do I can't get my RewriteRule to work in my .htaccess file.  I know the file is being processed.  If I screw up the syntax, I get a 500 error on the server.  If I use a Redirect line, it functions okay.  But RewriteRule won't work, even if I use static values.  No errors in the log.

My rule is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/content/$1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd fix on this.  While a Redirect 301 line would work fine in the .htaccess file, RewriteRule wouldn't.  However, there are multiple .htaccess files in the Wordpress file system, and putting the RewriteRule I wanted in a different .htaccess file did work.